# AWS API gateway returning null response(aws cdk)

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I tried integrating AWS Cloudfront, API gateway, and S3 to serve the S3 content using AWS CDK. One of the requirements of this stack is to verify a JWT token using our internal shared libraries, the token must be verified before we serve the caller any content.

So I had this set up:
**AWS Cloudfront** -> **API Gateway RestApi**(with custom authorizer) -> **AWSIntegration** configured using **S3**.

But I'm getting `{message: null}`, I'm stuck and have no idea what is going on here.

`distribution.ts` This is my **Cloudfront** distribution props setup

```
const customResponseHeadersPolicy = new ResponseHeadersPolicy(this.scope, `responseHeadersPolicy-${stage}-${region}`, {
            responseHeadersPolicyName: `responseHeadersPolicy-${stage}-${region}`,
            customHeadersBehavior: {
                customHeaders: [
                    { header: 'Cache-Control', value: 'no-cache', override: true }
                ]
            },
            securityHeadersBehavior: {
                contentSecurityPolicy: { contentSecurityPolicy: "script-src 'self' ajax.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com connect-cdn.atl-paas.net widget.intercom.io js.intercomcdn.com", override: true },
                contentTypeOptions: { override: true },
                referrerPolicy: { referrerPolicy: HeadersReferrerPolicy.ORIGIN, override: true },
                strictTransportSecurity: { accessControlMaxAge: Duration.seconds(hstsMaxAge), includeSubdomains: true, override: true },
                xssProtection: { protection: false, override: true }
            }
        });
const distroProps: any = {
    defaultBehavior: {
        origin: new RestApiOrigin(this.assetApi), //this API is the RestApi we set up in AssetApi.ts
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
        allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_GET_HEAD,
        cachedMethods: CachedMethods.CACHE_GET_HEAD,
        cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
        compress: false,
        smoothStreaming: false,
        responseHeadersPolicy: customResponseHeadersPolicy,
        originRequestPolicy: new OriginRequestPolicy(this.scope, 
            'staticAssetOriginPolicy', {
                 queryStringBehavior: OriginRequestQueryStringBehavior.all(),
             })
    },
...
```

`AssetApi.ts` This is the **API Gateway RestApi** setup

```
public createFormsAssetApi() {
        const api = new RestApi(this.scope, 'asset-api', {
            restApiName: "Static assets provider",
            description: "Serves assets from the S3 bucket.",
            binaryMediaTypes: ["*/*"],
            minimumCompressionSize: 0,
        })

        const role = new Role(this.scope, 'staticAuthorizerRole', {
            roleName: `staticAuthorizerLambdaRole-${this.props.stage}-${this.props.stageConfig.region}`,
            assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com')
        });

        role.addToPolicy(new PolicyStatement({
            resources: [this.props.stageConfig.s3BucketArn],
            actions: ["s3:Get"],
        }))

        const authorizerFn = createFunction(this.scope, 'staticAssetAuthorizer', this.props, {
            TENANT_URL: `${this.props.stageConfig.cssProps.tenantUrl}/tenant/3/tenant` // The base endpoint for the Tenant service
        }, '', Duration.minutes(1));
        authorizerFn.grantInvoke(role);

        const authorizer = new RequestAuthorizer(this.scope, 'staticAssetHeaderAuthorizer', {
            handler: authorizerFn,
            identitySources: [IdentitySource.queryString('jwt')]
        })

        const s3Integration = new AwsIntegration({
            service: "s3",
            integrationHttpMethod: "GET",
            path: `bookmarked-${this.props.stage}-storage/{folder}/{key}`,
            options: {
                credentialsRole: role,
                integrationResponses: [
                    {
                        statusCode: "200",
                        responseParameters: {
                            "method.response.header.Content-Type": "integration.response.header.Content-Type",
                        },
                    },
                ],
                requestParameters: {
                    "integration.request.path.folder": "method.request.path.folder",
                    "integration.request.path.key": "method.request.path.key",
                },
            }
        })

        api.root
            .addResource("{folder}")
            .addResource("{key}")
            .addMethod('GET', s3Integration, {
                methodResponses: [
                    {
                        statusCode: '200',
                        responseParameters: {
                            'method.response.header.Content-Type': true
                        },
                    },
                ],
                requestParameters: {
                    "method.request.path.folder": true,
                    "method.request.path.key": true,
                    "method.request.header.Content-Type": true,
                },
                authorizationType: AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
                authorizer: authorizer,
            })

        return api;
    }
```

When client-side makes a request to the **Cloudfront** URL, I expect the content hosted on S3 will be served, but instead I get this outcome， it's a 500 error.
[image]

Anything I did wrong or missing?

Comment: Waht is your authorizer ?

Comment: It is a Lambda function, I wrapped it with our internal libraries to verify the jwt token. The authorizer will return {isAuthorized: true} as response data.

Comment: that where the message {message: null} comes from I think, did you check lambda auth logs ?

Comment: Yes I checked, the token verification is passed

Comment: I think you are right @LinPy, I removed the authorizer, and it works! Now I have to figure out why the authorizer is problematic.

Comment: If your goal is to cache the content in CloudFront you should not hit the API Gateway for authorisation. Check the [signed cookie approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) to control access.